# How to write a c++ function what can return either iterator or reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

As far as I can tell in c++ there is no common base class that covers both iterator and reverse_iterator.

The only suggestion I have seen so far is to get around this using templates (
[How to write a function that takes an iterator or collection in a generic way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448119/how-to-write-a-function-that-takes-an-iterator-or-collection-in-a-generic-way) )

However this solution doesn't seem to work for me.

```
class MyClass
{
    template<typename Iter> Iter* generate_iterator(...params...)
    {
        //returns either a vector::iterator or vector::reverse_iterator
    }
    template<typename Iter> void do_stuff(Iter *begin, Iter *end)
    {
        //does stuff between elements specified by begin and end
        //I would like this function to remain agnostic of which direction it is working in!
    }
    void caller()
    {
        //I would like this function to remain agnostic of which direction it is working in too...
           do_stuff(generate_iterator(blah),generate_iterator(foo));
    }
};
```

In this case, generate_iterator() cannot be used as desired because the compiler complains "generate_iterator is not a member of class MyClass" presumably because I haven't specified it (which I can't in practice as caller should be agnostic of the iterator type).

Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance!

**edit**: as Mark B pointed out generate_iterator must return a pointer - now corrected

**update**: just started using this http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/start_page.html and it seems to work...

Comment: What is the logic you've envisioned `generate_iterator` performing to return an iterator?

Comment: It's to do with a car driving down a Street.  The network representation of my roadmap consists of two edges per street, one for each direction, representing the network connectivity, while the street object holds the shape of the thing.  Sometimes the edge needs to know its shape. If it is the forward edge for the street, it gets an iterator to the street's defining vector of x,y points; if it is the reverse edge it gets a reverse iterator to those points.

Comment: So in more abstract terms, it compares a parameter attached to the vector from which the iterator will come, to a parameter attached to MyClass, and uses these to determine the direction of the iterator.

Comment: Why are you returning/using pointers to iterators? That makes no sense whatsoever. The next question can you figure out which kind of iterator needs to be returned based on the the type of a parameter or a property of that type? If so, you can use sfinae to pick the right function, which still leaves the question of how to inform the caller about the type of iterator. Also `boost::any` comes to mind.

Comment: @honk Probably that's even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you can't write a function that returns two different types. In your template case it will return one or the other depending on the instantiation. You could possibly return a base pointer to a polymorphic iterator but that would cause me to ask what you're really trying to do here. Even the standard containers don't try to do that: They have `begin` and `rbegin` to distinguish properly. I would suggest having two separate functions that each do the right thing and return one type of iterator or the other as context dictates.

As a side, note that you can't implicitly determine a template instantiation of a type that's only used for the return type of a function.

Comment: Good point, I will have to return Iter* from generate_iterator.  But only generate_iterator knows whether the result will be forward or reverse, so can't implement separate methods.

Comment: On the other hand, Adobe has an `any_iterator` type that performs erasure on iterators, which seems to indicate that it is not so uncommon to consider the implementation of non-templated code that can use different iterator types...

Comment: Thanks for the any_iterator idea, googling for it found me this implementation of the same thing http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/start_page.html

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own iterator class that knows how to go both directions. Encapsulate both types of iterator and internally select whichever one you were initialized with.

Here's a start:

```
template<typename Container>
class BiIterator
{
public:
    BiIterator(Container::iterator i) : m_fwd(i), m_isforward(true) {}
    BiIterator(Container::reverse_iterator i) : m_rev(i), m_isforward(false) {}
    bool operator==(const BiIterator & left, const BiIterator & right);
    Container::value_type & operator*()
    {
        if (m_isforward)
            return *m_fwd;
        return *m_rev;
    }
    const Container::value_type & operator*() const;
    BiIterator & operator++()
    {
        if (m_isforward)
            ++m_fwd;
        else
            ++m_rev;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    Container::iterator         m_fwd;
    Container::reverse_iterator m_rev;
    bool                        m_isforward;
};
```

Comment: +1.  I might call it something like AmbiIterator (as in ambidextrous) in order not to create confusion with bidirectional iterators.  Additional methods may be required depending on how it's used.

Comment: @Adrian, I just picked the first name that came to mind - I like your suggestion too. And I did say the code was just a start, there are certainly more methods required, and I'm probably missing a `typename` or two as well.

Answer (score 1):

By using boost tuple and boost any , your problem can be easily solved. I wrote a example by using boost::any , see below:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
using boost::any_cast;
#define MSG(msg) cout << msg << endl;
boost::any getIterator(std::vector<int>& vec, bool bReverse)
{
    if(!bReverse)
        return boost::any(vec.begin());
    else
        return boost::any(vec.rbegin());
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> myvec;
    myvec.push_back(1);
    myvec.push_back(2);
    myvec.push_back(3);


    typedef std::vector<int>::iterator vecIter;
    typedef std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator vecRIter;
    try
    {
        boost::any iter  = getIterator(myvec, false);
        boost::any iter2 = getIterator(myvec, true);
        vecIter  it1 = any_cast<vecIter>(iter);
        vecRIter it2 = any_cast<vecRIter>(iter2);
        MSG(*it1);//output 1
        MSG(*it2);//output 3
        return true;
    }
    catch(const boost::bad_any_cast &)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html).

```
boost::variant< reverse_iterator, iterator >
generate_iterator(...) {
  if(...) return iterator();
  else return reverse_iterator();
}

// user code
boost::variant< reverse_iterator, iterator > v = generate_iterator();

if(reverse_iterator* it = boost::get<reverse_iterator>(v))
  ...;
else if(...)
  ...;
```

Although the `variant` is better accessed through a visitor.

The downside is that you need some boiler plate to extract the proper type and is exactly the reason why something like `any_iterator` might be a more sensible choice.